# How do I import my JSON array into Firebase as a FirebaseArray?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a large JSON file which contains an array. I am using Firebase for my app's backend and I want to use FirebaseArray to store the data.

It is simple to create a FirebaseArray from my Angular app and add data to it, but the nature of my app is that I have fetched data which I need to first import into Firebase somehow.

On the Firebase website the only option for importing is from a JSON. When I import my JSON file, the result is an object with numerical keys, which I realize is like an array, but has a major issue.

```
{
  "posts": {
    "0": {
      "id": "iyo0iw",
      "title": "pro patria mori"
    },
    "1": {
      "id": "k120iw",
      "title": "an english title"
    },
    "2": {
      "id": "p6124w",
      "title": "enim pablo espa"
    }
  }
}
```

Users are able to change the position of items, and the position of an item is also how items are uniquely identified. With multiple users this means the following problem can occur.

- Sarah: Change post[0] title to "Hello everyone"
- Trevor: Swap post[1] position with post[2]
- Sarah: Change post[1] title to "This is post at index 1 right?"

If the following actions happen in a short space of time, Firebase doesn't know for sure what Sarah saw as post[1] when they changed the title, and can't know for sure which post object to update.

What I want is a way to import my JSON file and have the arrays become [FirebaseArrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray), not objects with numerical keys, which are like arrays and share the issue described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you imported into your database is, in fact, an array.  Firebase Realtime Database only really represents data as a nested hierarchy of key/value pairs.  An array is just a set of key/value pairs where the the keys are all numbers, typically starting at 0.  That's exactly the structure you're showing in your question.

Comment: Yes I know this is an array technically, but my question specifically asks about FirebaseArray's, which are special objects that have unique id's as keys. Because multiple people may change the day (and can change the position of items) arrays are a bad idea for my app. Read more about it here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: It sounds like you just need another field in each post that determines its order relative to the other children under 'posts'.  You can query for that order using orderByChild.  The index/key of the child doesn't really matter at all in this case because the other value determines the display order.

Answer (score 2):

To generate the sort of data that would be created by writing to the database using an AngularFire [FirebaseArray](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasearray), you would need to pre-process your JSON.

Firebase push IDs are generated on the client and you can generate one by calling `push` without arguments.

You could convert an array to an object with Firebase push ID keys like this:

```
let arr = ["alice", "bob", "mallory"];
let obj = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  let key = firebase.database().ref().push().key;
  acc[key] = val;
  return acc;
}, {});
```